# Dropping options of exposed filters breaks when user is logged

Tags: views

I have a weird problem with Views exposed filters.

When I click on some exposed filters the dropping options are appearing, but when I hover with the mouse, dropping options are immediately dissapearing without letting me choose any of them. This problem only occurs when user is logged, no matter what role is using. 
I've disabled the administration module, but the problem still remains.

Using exposed filter as a block doesn't have this problem and anonymous users too.

The same problem I've experienced in my other website too.

Comment: i think its because of css issue

Comment: That was first that I checked, z-indexing, floating, position etc... but the problem still remains. It must be from something else. I've searched lot's of threads, but I didn't find any similar.

Comment: Try to clear CSS cache manually, by deleting `/sides/*/files/css/*`. Did it cause them to fail for anons too?

Comment: If you mean by emptying the cache, I've tried many times. There is no such css file in sites/*files/css/*, 'cos I didn't enable any caching.

Comment: Yep, I guess Bala is right. It's CSS issue, but I still cannot find the reason. When I put exposed filter into a custom block, it's working, but when I replace the position of that block on my theme near to the view content, the dropping options with hovering the mouse dissapeared again. Damn, I'm still struggling to solve this mystery. I've tried to put position:absolute, z-index:100 to exposed form and lower z-index to view content, but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As Bala said, it is a CSS issue. I finally fixed it.
The problem comes from my `<#section id="main">`. It's a wrapper to all the main content area in my theme.
It has `display:inline`, but when I change it into `display:inline-block` or by deleting the display, the dropping options are working flawlessly.